# Centos 6.2: Unable to open terminal after vbox save state

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I'm experiencing this issue frequently. Usually, I work on my Centos 6.2 in VBox for a while and then close it by saving state (going to other machines or doing host work). Then, I resume my session in VBox and I have the following issues

1. Internet is down. The connection is lost.
2. Trying to restart the connection hangs the menu/machine
3. Can't open the terminal (it says loading and never open)

Any body has an explanation/idea for what's going on.